# How to change navigation bar text color in xamarin forms android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Im using Xamarin Forms and i want to change color of Navigationbar in Android.
Im using this code:

`MainPage = new NavigationPage 
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.Lime,
    BarTextColor = Color.Purple
};`

The first property (`BarBackgroundColor`) was worked, second property not worked (`BarTextColor`).

Please kindly answer me.

Answer (score 3):

you can set in your app.xaml  and it will override it

```
  <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White"/>
  </Style>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set the text color on Android 5.0 or higher, you need to set the `Theme` of the `MainActivity`. Here is a simple one that should work...

```
[Activity(
    Label = "Some App Title", 
    Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
    MainLauncher = true, 
    Theme = "@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light"
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting those attributes in app.xaml only will reliably do the job!

Answer (score -1):

```
var page = new navigationPage(new yourPage());
page.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#123456");
```

It will change `yourPage()` bar color