# Xamarin.Forms change background color of ContentPage.ToolbarItems

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

With my Xamarin cross-platform app, I have a drop-down menu which is created with the following XAML code:

```
<ContentPage>
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add another child to my account" Order="Secondary" Priority="1" Clicked="AddAnotherChildClick"   />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Delete child from my account" Order="Secondary" Priority="2" Clicked="DeleteChildClick" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Log Out" Order="Secondary" Priority="3" Clicked="LogOutClick" />
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

I need to be able to control the background color and text color of the menu. It is currently grey with white text (see screenshot). I would like it black with orange text.

How can I change this - ideally using a global style?

[image: Screenshot of the menu as it is now]

Comment: Are you try use `NavigationPage` method?

Comment: I navigate between pages like this: Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyPage)(); Is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you creating NavigationPage every time you navigate or set your main page once to NavigationPage and use Push/Pop?

Comment: NavigationPage each time to prevent the back button from working (it's a requirement).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Navigation page then you can do the follow:

```
        var navPage = new NavigationPage(new YourPage());
        this.MainPage = navPage;

        navPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Orange;
        navPage.BarTextColor = Color.Black;
```

It will work on iOS but on Android 5.0 and above the text color will not change. To change it see this link

[How to change navigation bar text color in xamarin forms android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811104/how-to-change-navigation-bar-text-color-in-xamarin-forms-android)

Comment: need to change secondary toolbar background color. not bar background color.